# can you send amazon lambda error logs via email

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

is there a way to send via email the same error log that would appear in cloudwatch for a Lambda function?

Comment: what part of cloudwatch logs do you want to email ?

Comment: @varnit what do you mean? The full log relating to the lambda that failed obviously.

Comment: i mean do you want just the exception that might occur in your lambda function or execution time and other extra stuff that are part of cloudwatch log

Comment: The exception is what I am mainly after. Other information would be useful too but If complicated to get is not strictly necessary.

Comment: yes you can you need to write a lambda where you can use `client.describe_log_streams` and extarct the log and make it formatted  and then in that lambda you can do sns.publish and make formatted string of that log extratcion and  send over.....

Answer (score 0):

To deliver logs you can create cloudwatch subscription filter, you can click on your log group and then click on stream on AWS lambda and select your lambda function .

[image: stream to aws lambda]

the logs will be delivered in gzip format and you can unzip them using this code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var zlib = require('zlib');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create sendTemplatedEmail params 
var params = {
  Destination: { /* required */
    CcAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
      /* more CC email addresses */
    ],
    ToAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
      /* more To email addresses */
    ]
  },
  Source: 'EMAIL_ADDRESS', /* required */
  Template: 'TEMPLATE_NAME', /* required */
  TemplateData: '{ \"REPLACEMENT_TAG_NAME\":\"REPLACEMENT_VALUE\" }', /* required */
  ReplyToAddresses: [
      'EMAIL_ADDRESS',
  ],
};

exports.handler = function(input, context) {
    var payload = new Buffer(input.awslogs.data, 'base64');
    zlib.gunzip(payload, function(e, result) {
        if (e) { 
            context.fail(e);
        } else {
            result = JSON.parse(result.toString('ascii'));
            console.log("Event Data:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
           var sendPromise = new AWS.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12- 
           01'}).sendTemplatedEmail(params).promise();

          // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
           sendPromise.then(
             function(data) {
               console.log(data);
             }).catch(
                 function(err) {
                   console.error(err, err.stack);
             });  
           context.succeed();
        }
    });
};
```

This code basically fetch the logs, unzip them and email it using AWS SES 
sdk for more information click on these resources.

[cloudwatch log lambda subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample)
[Sending email using Simple email service sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html)

Comment: I'm sorry you have to use cloudwatch subscribtion filter for delivering logs to email